# How can I confirm something in JavaScript and then use

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form and when you submit it, a JavaScript message appears.

```
$message = "Want to insert?";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.confirm('$message');</script>";
```

And what I want to do is, if the person clicks 'OK' it inserts values in the database, if not it cancels it.

```
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$ano = $_POST['ano'];
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$link = " ";
```

Comment: If you want it to be interactive, you must use AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words, **PHP executes first**, and then client side JavaScript executes. If you want it to be interactive, you must use AJAX, which will allow you to send PHP command controlled by JavaScript.

If I were you, I would do this way:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
  $.post("path/to/php.php", {data: you_need_to_send}, function (response) {
    if (response == "OK")
      alert("All Done!");
  });
else
  alert("You cancelled the insertion.");
```

> ***Note:*** Here, `$.post()` is a jQuery implementation of AJAX POST method. Just for ease of explanation I gave this. Please don't shout at me for answering a jQuery way for a JavaScript question.

---

**Update**

You can use `onsubmit` of the form to make this possible. Make sure you give a `return` inside the event:

```html
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  <input />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Run the above snippet and check it out.

Comment: I dont know nothing about AJAX thats the problem

Comment: @Leonoliveira Is it okay if you can use jQuery in your application? The documentation is excellent. But did you understand what I said in my answer?

Comment: i can. i dont know nothing but AJAX but your explanation is really good thx man

Answer (score 3):

Use `<form>` tag, and handle the onsubmit event. once he clicked 'OK' on message box submit the form.

Once the form gets submitted, In server side (PHP) write a code to get the data ( either by GET/POST which ever way you are sending)  and insert into the table.

Comment: Ah... This is a better way. Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: That's the legit way to use it. Client side interactions shouldn't be controlled from server end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data using a request to your server. You cannot use JavaScript to write in you database directly since you already use **PHP**

But to confirm the user before you send your request or  you can use this in your JavaScript code before you send your request.

```js
if (confirm('Your Message')) {
    // User click OK
    // Send your data to server using a Request
} else {
    // User click cancel
}
```